# Cirlce Detection Without Hough

Tags: python, opencv, detection

i have used the Circle Hough transform to detect the Circles in this Image , by using this code in python , but now i want to detect the circles by using another method , is there any other method the detect the circle except the circle Hough transform

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("Resources/coin0.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur= cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
# center


dp=1.1
minDis=10
param1=150
param2=40
minRadius=0
maxRadius=0

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp, minDis,
                        param1 =param1, param2 =param2, minRadius = minRadius, maxRadius = maxRadius)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0, :]: ## Draw circle on the circles

 #  draw   the    outer  circle
 cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0),2)
 #  draw   the    center of the    circle
 cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255),2)





cv2.imshow("Image",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxkpw.jpg)

Comment: Threshold each coin one at a time as its own image. Then draw the bounding circle. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8ce13c24081bbc7151e9326f412190f1

Comment: @fmw42  What I meant is that I need another approach or algorithm to detect the circles, besides the CHT, I need to implement it in Python . do you have an idea ?

Comment: I made a suggestion above. Threshold each coin one at a time. Then it is is simple to get the minimum enclosing circle.